# What 300mm lens to get for my Nikon camera for wildlife photography in a national park?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, nikon, telephoto, wildlife

I'm shopping for a 300mm lens for my Nikon D60. Which lens do you suggest? I want to use it mostly to capture images of animals in the Kruger National Park?

Comment: What budget do you have?

Comment: Have you considered renting rather than buying?  For a once in a lifetime type trip a pro-body and more rugged lens would be worth the investment...

Answer (score 4):

[Did you try searching? You only have three choices as you can see.](http://www.neocamera.com/search_lens.php?mount=nikon&focalwide=300:to:301&focusmotor=SS&prime=1&by=feature)

One of them is stabilized (and weather-sealed but that does not count on your camera), the other two are not. Since you are shooting things that move, the stabilization impact will matter most when you shoot the animals at rest. The Nikkor AF-S 300mm F/2.8G ED-IF VR II and the Sigma 300mm F/2.8 let one stop more light in but beware that it they weigh at least one kilo more than the non-stabilized one. Most shots are taken from a Jeep in Kruger park, so it is recommended to bring a beanbag for support to cushion the lens against the window/door frame for stabilization. This means the [Sigma 300mm F/2.8](http://www.neocamera.com/lens/sigma/300mm_f2.8_ex_apo_dg_hsm/nikon) will probably be a great compromise among these.

**EDIT** In case you do not mind a zoom, there are quite a few more which [reach to at least 300mm](http://www.neocamera.com/search_lens.php?mount=nikon&focaltele=300:min&zoom=1&by=feature&focusmotor=SS). Note that some of these are quite slow (F/6.3) at the long end which is not ideal for wildlife.

Comment: What about Sigma?

Comment: And, on a slightly different note, what about zooms in this range?

Comment: Sigma has lots and lots of options http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&Ntt=Sigma+300mm+Nikon&A=endecaSearch&N=0&Q=&InitialSearch=yes Nikon also has many zoom lens options http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?ntt=300&refineSearchString=300&ci=1&N=4291315846+4288584247 You also could get a teleconverter.

Comment: The search link is for *Nikon mount* with built-in focus motor, so if Sigma made such 300mm it would show up. Actually, **if they eventually do, it will show up** :)

Comment: On a different note. Zooms are OK, just not what was asked. Plus, 300mm is not a range :) but I'll add it to the answer an other option.

Comment: Oh so pedantic. :) Read that as "Zooms _which include this focal length_ in their range", of course.

Comment: The Sigma 300mm f/2.8 has a built-in ultrasonic motor and Sigma lists it as able to auto-focus on the Nikon D60 and other Nikon cameras without a focus motor. I have no personal experience with it, so maybe I'm missing something, but perhaps there's an error in your database?

Comment: Well if you are going that route, autofocus wasn't asked for either.

Comment: @mattdm - Looks like it does. There will be a DB update tonight. The information from manufacturers is not always complete at the time we receive it. I've received some lenses with weight as TBD on more than one occasion from Sigma!

Comment: Not trying to be pedantic but usually people look for a lens that can autofocus on their camera but when they specify a single focal-length, they mean a prime lens. Not everyone knows that a *prime* lens is. This based on personal experience not on empirical research but has rarely proven wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I would get the Nikon 300mm f/4. I chose a 300mm f/4 as my first lens when I got into wildlife photography and it's been excellent, I've used it extensively.

- non-Nikon lenses will autofocus more slowly, which is a hindrance with wildlife
- f/2.8 lenses, while having some advantages, are a lot heavier and a great deal more expensive.
- Image Stabilisation is very useful even from a car
- Teleconverters can be useful .. but image quality (and autofocus speed) takes a hit. I have one but rarely use it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider a zoom like the Sigma 120-300.  Driving around a park you may get much closer to animals than you think, and being able to zoom out is quite useful - changing lenses as little as possible while on a dusty road in an open vehicle is a good thing.

Also consider getting a 1.4x TC.  Sometimes 300mm may not seem like nearly long enough and then you will appreciate the extra range... it comes with a price though, you lose a stop or two of light.

Whatever you get practice with it at the zoo and in someones car before you leave so you are used to how it works.

Comment: Generally in game parks in SA you're confined to the roads, and are not often that close to the animals.   Except when they decide to cross the road which doesn't happen that often.

Comment: I was in other parks in Botswana where we were also confined to roads, but a number of animals still got very close (crossing the road or being very near it).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the fixed 300mm lenses Itai has mentioned, you could get a Nikon 180mm f/2.8 plus a 1.6x or 2.0x teleconverter.  This would give you between 290 f/4 and 360mm f/5.6, depending on the teleconverter.  This would cost much less that the 300mm f/2.8, and probably less than the 300mm f/4, and you might find it more versatile (using with and without the TC).

Another versatile options would be the Sigma 150-500mm f/5.6 (slow but has image stabilisation) or the Nikon 80-400mm f/4.5-5.6 VR.

Comment: I'd not go for either of those 2 zooms. AF is too slow, especially in low light (I own the 170-500 btw, it's a nice if somewhat soft lens in bright light, but quickly fails when things get dusky). A better alternative would be a Sigma 70-200 f/2.8 with 2x TC.